# Connection refused exception when starting impalad

Tags: hadoop, connection, impala

When I start impalad after having built impala2.0.0 successfully, i meet such an error

```
[root@localhost impala-2.0.0-cdh5.2.0]# ./bin/start-impalad.sh -use_statestore=false
ls: cannot access /root/projects/impala-2.0.0-cdh5.2.0/testdata/target/dependency/*.jar: No such file or directory
E1201 17:06:38.832816  4080 impala-server.cc:213] Could not read the HDFS root directory at hdfs://localhost:20500. Error was: 
Call From localhost/127.0.0.1 to localhost:20500 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
E1201 17:06:38.832924  4080 impala-server.cc:215] Aborting Impala Server startup due to improper configuration
```

I have already started hadoop using `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh` script.

```
[root@localhost impala-2.0.0-cdh5.2.0]# jps
2301 ResourceManager
2115 SecondaryNameNode
1918 DataNode
2396 NodeManager
1809 NameNode
4157 Jps
```

But when i use `natstat -anp | grep LISTEN`, it sounds that port `20500` were not listened.
What can i do if i want to start up the port `20500` to be listened.

Regards

Comment: `No such file or directory` for `dependency/*.jar` under `target` folder, could be deleted at `clean` time. check whether it is there or not.

Comment: But I have compiled the impala using ./build_all.sh -noclean command.

Comment: `Aborting Impala Server startup due to improper configuration` please check the impala configuration files.

Comment: everything goes well when i change the configuration files.